# secure PRFs and XOR

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Let $F(k,x)$ be a secure PRF over $(\mathcal{K},\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ where $\mathcal{K} = \mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y} = \{0,1\}^n$.

Why is the function $F_1(k, (x_1, x_2)) = F(k, x_1) \oplus F(k, x_2)$ an unsecure PRF while the function $F_2(k, x) = F(k, x) \oplus x$ is a secure PRF?

Comment: What's $F_1(k, (x, x))$ for any $x$?

Comment: Suppose I have a random algorithm $A$ which distinguishes $x \mapsto F_2(k, x)$ from a uniform random function $G\colon \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$.  Can you define a random algorithm $A'$, using $A$ as a subroutine, which distinguishes $x \mapsto F(k, x)$ from a uniform random function $G\colon \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$?  If you're not sure how, can you quote the definition of the PRF-advantage of an algorithm $A$ for distinguishing $F_2$?

Comment: $F_1$ is a function that gets as input a key $k \in \mathcal{K}$ and a pair of elements $x_1,x_2 \in \mathcal{X}$ and returns $F(k, x_1) \oplus F(k, x_2)$.

Comment: Yes,  so what happens if $x_1 = x_2$?  What is $F(k, x) \oplus F(k, x)$?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage $F_1$ would return a $n$-bit $0$ string.

Comment: Does a uniform random function $G\colon \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$ often return an $n$-bit $0$ string?

Comment: I understood now. As the adversary can send a lot of inputs and get the outputs, one can build an adversary that guesses it is pseudo-random always that it gives $x_1$ and $x_2$ and get a $n$-bit 0 string as output from the challenger, what doesn't happen in $F_2$, am I right?